# Mollifiers: Integral Bound

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis

Desirable is an example such that:
$$\varphi_0\in\mathcal{C}^\infty_0:\quad\int_0^\infty\left|\varphi_0^{(n)}(s)\right|\mathrm{d}s\leq2^n$$
*(It should not exist as one would obtain entire elements for generators of semigroups.)*

How to prove that they must always exceed the bound?

Comment: Seeing the accepted answer, I understand that the support of $\varphi_0$ must be contained in $(0, \infty)$. In particular, $\varphi_0^{(n)}(0)=0$ for all $n$. Right? (It would be interesting to see if the result still holds if this last condition is removed. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the Fourier transform of $\varphi_0$. We have
$$
\widehat{\varphi_0^{(n)}}(\xi)=C^n\,\xi^n\,\hat{\varphi_0}(\xi),
$$
where $C$ is a constant deppending on the particular definition of the Fourier transform used. Then
$$
|\widehat{\varphi_0^{(n)}}(\xi)|=|C|^n\,|\xi|^n\,|\hat{\varphi_0}(\xi)|\le\int|\varphi_0^{(n)}(x)|\,dx\le2^n\quad\forall\xi\in\mathbb{R},\quad\forall n\in\mathbb{N}.
$$
Then
$$
|\hat{\varphi_0}(\xi)|\le\Bigl(\frac{2\,|C|}{|\xi|}\Bigr)^n\quad\forall\xi\in\mathbb{R},\quad\forall n\in\mathbb{N}.
$$
This implies that $\hat{\varphi_0}$ is supported on $[-2\,|C|,2\,|C|]$, which is not possible since $\varphi_0$ has also compact support.

Comment: Where does this estimate come from: $|\xi|^n|\hat{\varphi_0}(\xi)|\leq\int|\varphi_0^{(n)}(x)|\mathrm{d}x$

Comment: Why is it impossible to have both compactly supported: $\varphi_0,\hat{\varphi_0}\in\mathcal{C}^\infty_0$

Comment: First comment: $|\hat f(\xi)|\le\|f\|_1$. Second comment: it is a well known result in harmonic analysis. If $f$ has compact support then $\hat f$ is analytic, so that if $\hat f$ vanishes in an open set, it is identically equal to $0$.

Comment: Ok thanks :) ...besides shouldn't the second line read: $|C|^n\,|\xi|^n\,|\hat{\varphi_0}(\xi)|=|\widehat{\varphi_0^{(n)}}(\xi)|\le \ldots$

Comment: It is a mater of taste.

Comment: Looong ago in linear algebra I learned that the order of reasoning should (not must) be reflected also in a chain of equations though of course they're equivalent. So of course $a=b$ implies also $b=a$. But if you say $a=b$ and $b\leq c$ I guess you would merge them as $a=b\leq c$ rather than illogically $b=a\leq c$. Sure after all they're equivalent so a matter of taste, but it is hard for the reader to follow if order of reasoning is not reflected in the chain of equalities. In fact, I read this first time I saw it really the wrong way (not knowing too much about it). You decide...